# React build removes name of component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, build, create-react-app

I'm making a fullscreen rotating noticeboard in React with create-react-app.

The `App` component contains many `Screen` components, each one containing one child component (named such as WiFiPassword, OpenTimes, Events...) - and the `Screen` component checks if the current item from `App` is the name of it's child, and if it is then it shows that screen, if not then it hides it.

This is the code where the values are checked:

```
class Screen extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const active = this.props.active; // The active item, from parent state
    const elemName = this.props.children.type.name; //The name of the child class
    ...
    if(active === elemName){
      //If we have a match, then show this screen
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This works really well when running in development.

When I run `npm run build` and the process is finished, I load up the app and it doesn't work - it appears that the build process scrubs the class names from elements, which then means nothing is ever shown.

When I `console.log()` both the active prop and the child class name I get this:

`active: WiFiPassword`

`elemName: t`

Whatever screen it is on, `elemName`, which is the name of `Screen`'s child, is always `t`

Is there a way to retain the name of a component in react through the build process?

Comment: This question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but luckily X is obvious from the question. The solution is to only render the one visible `Screen` in your `App`'s `render()`.

Comment: Why do you need to refer to the component by its name as opposed to, say the child's index?

Comment: So each <Screen> has only one child, which is the contents of the screen. The <Screen> just handles animation, and when to display, whereas the content is stuff added by non-web-developers. I think I'll instead, pass a prop to the <Screen> and then dynamically pull in the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way around this: instead of relying on the class name, I instead imported every one of my `<Screen>` elements using a `screens/index.js` file:

`...
export {default as Welcome} from './Welcome'
export {default as WiFi} from './WiFi' 
...`

Then imported that index, file with each screen available to me:

`import * as Screens from './screens'`

Then I use whatever screen I want, depending on the same logic from within App:

`const Component = Screens[this.state.slide];
<Component/>`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like, you should switch to use react-router-dom, because you will have a good way to manage your screens. There is a good component Switch, that shows one component at the time:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
  <Route component={NoMatch}/>
</Switch>
```

more information here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: Thanks for this, however my app doesn't need routing (it's running on a big TV in kiosk mode) which would normally be the way forwards.